# Método onKey() não é acionado da maneira desejada

Tags: java, android

Eu estou tentando capturar a tecla enter para pular de um `EditText` para outro. O problema é que o método `onKey()` não é chamado quando aperto uma tecla, pra ele ser executado eu preciso segurar a tecla por um tempo.

**Meu código:**

```
 this.mHolder.editLargura.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                mHolder.editComprimento.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

O que posso fazer pra ele ser acionado sem que eu precise segurar uma tecla?

Comment: A documentação do `onKeyListener` diz que ele só é acionado com certeza por teclados físicos. Teclados em software normalmente não ativam esse listener, a não ser em alguns casos especiais. Não sei qual é o seu caso, mas provavelmente você vai precisar de outro tipo de listener, como esse: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html

Comment: Obrigado, isso já ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A documentação do onKeyListener diz que ele só é acionado com certeza por teclados físicos. Teclados em software normalmente não ativam esse listener, a não ser em alguns casos especiais. Não sei qual é o seu caso, mas provavelmente você vai precisar de outro tipo de listener, como esse: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html

Comment: Só pra fechar, eu consegui fazer com que o enter pule para o próximo EditText adicionando essa linha no XML na tag do EditText em questão: android:inputType="textImeMultiline"